# (spherical tumouroid)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

For the Logistic model it is denoted:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{dV(t)}{dt}=\alpha V(t)-\beta V(t)^2\\
V(0)=v_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Now I need to find the exact solution?

I get to the stage where:

$\frac{-log(\alpha-\beta V(t))}{\alpha}+\frac{V(t)}{\alpha}=t+c_1$

However, how do I go about finding the exact solution?

Comment: I added the "ordinary-differential-equations" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: [Bernoulli differential equation on WIkipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Looking at what you wrote, I suppose that you rewrote
$$V'=\alpha V - \beta V^2$$as
$$\frac 1{t'}=\alpha V - \beta V^2\implies t'= \frac 1{\alpha V - \beta V^2}=\frac{1}{\alpha  V}-\frac{\beta }{\alpha  (\beta  V-\alpha )}$$ Now, integrate properly both sides, isolate $V$ and apply the condition.

Comment: @Ironlegend. This is exactly the point ! The equation is separable. On my side, I do not understand how you did get the last equation your wrote.